# Check if changes made to any of the input fileds

Tags: javascript, angularjs

http://jsfiddle.net/r2ohsuty/

Tried to use angularjs to check whether user make any changes or not to any of the input fields, but not sure where I messed up, it doesn't work as expected.

```
function AppCtrl($scope) {

  $scope.submit = function(name, age, gender) {

    var fields = {
      name: name,
      age: age,
      gender: gender
    };
    for (key in fields) {
      if (fields[key] === $scope[key]) {
        $scope.result = 'no changes';
      } else {
        $scope.result = 'have changes';
      }

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Changes compared to what? You're comparing the current value to the current value, which is always true.

Comment: What is the use-case?

Comment: @Juhana current value compare with newly submitted value. I thought the scope[key] will be updated if user change the input's value?

Comment: @Tushar if user changed any of the input value, print `have changes` else print `no changes`

Comment: You can use `ng-change` event handler.

Comment: @Tushar bind 3 inputs?

Comment: @Tushar but still in the end u have to check by comparing the value right?

Comment: I still don't understand what you want. The current value is, by definition, the newly submitted value. By "current value" do you mean the *previously* submitted value?

Comment: @Juhana when a user enter a page, the current value might be abc then he change one of them, now the result is bbc. I want to compare is abc equal to bbc.

Comment: Well then you have to save the "current value" when the user enters the page, not when they submit the form. http://jsfiddle.net/r2ohsuty/1/

Comment: @Juhana doesn't work.

Comment: save input values in `localStorage` and then compare change input values to already saved values.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you want:

```
function AppCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.originalValues = { name: "original name value", age: "original age value", gender: "origin gender value" }
    $scope.updatedValues = angular.copy($scope.originalValues)
    // Within your view. set ng-model of each input to the corresponding field 
    // Eg ng-model="updatedValues['name']"

    $scope.submit = function() {
        for (key in $scope.originalValues) {
            if ($scope.originalValues[key] === $scope.updatedValues[key]) {
                $scope.result = 'no changes';
            } else {
                $scope.result = 'have changes';
            }
        }
    }
}
```